# Como usar Material Icons com next.js?

Tags: react, webpack

```js
import Link from 'next/link';
import MaterialIcon from 'material-icons-react';

const Header = (props) => {
  return (
    <nav>
      <ul>
        {navOptions.map(nav => (
          <li>
            <Link href={nav.url}>
              <a>
                <MaterialIcon icon={nav.icon} />
                <span key={nav.icon}>{nav.name}</span>
              </a>
            </Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Header;
```

O código acima gera o seguinte erro:

[image: Erro]

Me parece que necessito de um loader, mas não consigo saber exatamente qual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vai necessitar do loader *@zeit/next-css*

```
npm install --save @zeit/next-css
```

Crie um arquivo next.config.js (sem o CSS Modules)

```
// next.config.js
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
module.exports = withCSS()
```

Mais informações:

https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/tree/master/packages/next-css